# Pass a PAUSE command to a START command in a batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Let's say I have a batch file with a bunch of lines each starting with `START` to run commands simultenously and I want each a new window that pops up to just pause when it's finished, instead of just closing, so that I could read the summary at the end.

`start myapp.exe && pause` doesn't work as the `pause` command just gets executed in the main window and doesn't get passed down with `START`. `CMD /k` works to prevent the window, but what I'd like to avoid that and use `PAUSE`.

It's important that I run these simultanously and I don't want to create a separate batch file for each line.

Any suggestions?

Comment: why would you want pause when `cmd /k` works better?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `start` command can only be used invoke a single internal or external command. To pass additional commands you have to pass the commands to a new instance of CMD and escape any special characters, to be able to pass them to the child process (CMD.EXE in this case).

```
start cmd /c myapp.exe ^& pause
```

As an addition, If command extensions are enabled (which is the default case) **"CMD "** can be used instead of just **cmd** or **cmd.exe**,...

Note that it has to be `"CMD "` with an extra space after `CMD` so it is different from `"CMD"`

Quoted from the start command help:

> If Command Extensions are enabled, external command invocation
>   through the command line or the START command changes as follows:
>   
> .
>   
> .
>   
> .
>   
> When executing a command line whose first token is the string "CMD "
>       without an extension or path qualifier, then "CMD" is replaced with
>       the value of the COMSPEC variable.  This prevents picking up CMD.EXE
>       from the current directory.

So a safer approach would be

```
start "" "CMD " /c myapp.exe ^& pause
```

It is functionally equivalent to

```
start "" "%COMSPEC%" /c myapp.exe ^& pause
```

And because the first quoted argument to the `start` command will be interpreted as the window title, A dummy title (in this case an empty title `""`) was passed as the first argument of the `start` command.

Answer (score -1):

You just need to escape the && operator with ^ like: `start myapp.exe ^&& pause`

But you better use the & operator that runs the second command no matter if the first command succeeds, otherwise if myapp.exe sets an error code, pause won't be run and the window will close before you can see it.

Comment: That doesn't work. &, &&, ^&&, ^&^& all just means there's a pause after each START so they're not passed down. Instead each pause just prevents running the next START in line automatically.